# Homebrew takes too long to install new PHP

Tags: php, homebrew

I'm using MacOS and trying to install new PHP version (trying to make minor update 8.0 to 8.1).

I use `brew update`

and added `brew tap shivammathur/php` repo

and run `brew install php@8.1`

However, it took so much time to install new version of PHP (15 mins and counting).

Is there a faster way to update local PHP or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Please qualify the formula name `php@8.1` with the tap name `shivammathur/php` while installing to make sure you are installing from the tap.

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.1
```

Comment: I also added that, but it took so much time.

Comment: Please provide the logs here in an issue.
https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php/issues